# Netbeans 8.0 300% cpu usage mac osx

Tags: macos, cpu-usage, netbeans

[image: alt]

This happens after a while of using netbeans with php web development. Anyone know if this is a common problem or not and if there is a fix. Don't want it to slowly kill the macbook air I just bought!